# finding Inverse of $f(x) =xe^x$

Tags: calculus, inverse, lambert-w

On my calculus text we were faced with the problem to find an inverse to $xe^x$ (that is, to give an explicit formula for the inverse and calculate its derivative and antiderivative).

When browsing stack exchange I found that the right answer is the Lambert $W$-function. However, our calc course never mentioned anything about the $W$-function. How would you go about solving this problem without a rigorous understanding of the Lambert $W$-function?

Comment: What does "find" mean, in your calculus text ? Is it "give an explicit formula", or "show that there exists" ?

Comment: It could also mean to graph the inverse.

Comment: Sorry for being unspecific, we were supposed to give an explicit formula and calculate its derivative and antiderivative.

Answer (score 0):

[image]The function $xe^x$ is monotonically increasing for all $y=xe^x\ge0$ it is therefore one to one and is invertible there (the inverse being the Lambert W function already mentioned). For $-e^{-1}\lt xe^x<0$ the inverse is double valued. For example, the equation $xe^x=-0.1$ has 2 solutions $x=-3.5771..$ and $x=-0.1118...$. For $xe^x<-e^{-1}$ it is not invertible. These features can be easily seen from the graph of $xe^x$